# SQL injection using SubQuery Select in Insert Statement

Tags: sql, sql-injection, sql-insert, subquery

I'm learning about SQL injection, and I've come across an SQL query that looks like the following.

The SQL query looks like:

```
INSERT INTO documents (name, filename, mimetype, sessid) VALUES ("name", "filename", "mimetype", "sessid");
```

I want to do something like:

```
INSERT INTO documents (name, filename, mimetype, sessid) VALUES ((SELECT * FROM level8.documents), "filename", "mimetype", "sessid");
```

or even

```
INSERT INTO documents (name, filename, mimetype, sessid) VALUES ((SELECT * FROM level8.documents), "filename", "mimetype", "sessid");
```

When I run this I get `error code: 1241.` when I run this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm sure there is a message as well.

Comment: @usr what? I don't understand.

Comment: Every error should come with a message

Comment: Where's the sql injection relevant part in all this?

Comment: @geomagas Maybe it's not relevant. It seems odd you would want to select * from the table and insert it into a a single field. It was more for context.

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to achieve? What's the expected output?

Comment: Is it like level8.documents has only one column and you want to insert all it's row values separated by a delimiter as a single row in main documents table? or is it like you want to insert multiple rows in documents table with each row with corresponding values from level8.documents table?

Comment: I'd love to drop all the data into the name, which is obviously displayed to the user. Although, at this point, if I can just verify that SQLi exists here, I'd be pretty happy.

Comment: Hmmmm... That would hardly work just like that... I'm guessing you'll have to come up with a better idea....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your select statement returns more than 1 columns.

Try

```
INSERT INTO documents (name, filename, mimetype, sessid) 
VALUES ((SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(names of all your columns) FROM 
level8.documents), "filename", "mimetype", "sessid");
```

Read more about subquery errors here.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-errors.html

Comment: I get an Error 1093 (ER_UPDATE_TABLE_USED) because i'm inserting into a table I'm also selecting everything from.

Comment: Then maybe a temporary table could be used that you create - insert all from documents - run the query - drop the temporary table

Comment: How about if I wanted to drop `SELECT @@VERSION` inplace of "name" ?

Comment: You cant drop SELECT @@Version? Its not a physical table. Or do you mean that you want to have the SQL version written as name?

Comment: Yeah, just have it written as name. Sorry, I'm overloading the term drop.

Comment: @NoahClark: You don't need `select` to do that. `INSERT INTO documents (name, filename, mimetype, sessid) 
VALUES (@@VERSION, "filename", "mimetype", "sessid");` would do it.